# How can I schedule a script in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

At last BigQuery supports using ; in the queries, so I can write more than one query in one "block", if I seperate them with semicolon.
If I run the code manually, it works. But I cannot schedule that.

When I want to schedule, I have two choices:

1. (New) Web UI: I must give a destination table. If I don't do it, I could not save the scheduled query. But all my queries are updates and inserts with different "destination tables". Like these:

UPDATE `project.exampledataset.a`
SET date = current_date()
WHEN TRUE
;

INSERT INTO `project.otherdataset.b`
SELECT c,d
FROM `project.otherdataset.c`

So I cannot even make a scheduling in the Web UI.

2. Classic UI: I tried this, because the official documentary states, that I should leave the "destination table" blank, and Classic UI allows it. I can setup the scheduling, but it doesn't run, when it should. I get the error message in email "Error status: Dataset specified in the query ('') is not consistent with Destination dataset 'exampledataset'."

AIK scripting (and using semicolon) is a very new feature in BigQuery, but I hope someone can help me.
Yes, I know that I could schedule every query one by one, but I would like to resolve it with one big script.

Comment: It is a bug. Please monitor https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142639061 to get notified when it is resolved.

Comment: I got it, thanks Yun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the scheduled query was defined earlier with destination dataset defined with APPEND/TRUNCATE type transaction. While updating the same scheduled query to a DML query, GUI doesn't show the dataset field / table name to update to NULL. Hence this error is coming considering the previously set dataset and table name in the scheduled query.

Hence the fix is to **delete the scheduled query** and create it from scratch with DML query option. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Scripting is supported in scheduled query now. However, scripting query, when being scheduled, doesn't support setting a destination table for now. You still need to use DDL/DML to make change to existing table.

E.g.:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE destinationTable AS
SELECT *
FROM sourceTable
WHERE date >= maxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, the BQ Console UI will let you create a new scheduled query without a destination dataset, but it won't let you update a prior SELECT to use DDL/DML block syntax. However, you can use the [BigQuery Data Transfer API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs) to update the destinationDatasetId field, via [transferconfigs/patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs/patch). Use [transferconfigs/list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs/list) to get the configId for a given scheduled query.

Note that you can either use the in-browser API Explorer, if you have the appropriate credentials, or write a programmatic solution. Also seems useful for setting/updating any other fields, including renaming scheduled queries.